# How do I get join() or wait() to work here? Java threads and concurrency

Tags: java, concurrency, thread-safety, wait

The code in this question was clearly too long so I've written an example you can just copy and paste that I think encompasses the conceptual problem I'm having.
Thanks to those who read all the way through the previous version!

Two files

One calls the other and passes an ArrayList.

The 2nd file alters the ArrayList and provides a getter for the first file to access the altered file.

How can I make the first file wait for the processing in the second file, before calling the getter. At the moment this code gives you a NullPointerException because the first file isn't waiting.

join() on the thread of execution doesn't seem to work, and if I use wait(), how do I notify() to the first file from the second file?

Here's the code:

```
public class Launcher implements Runnable {

private ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
private ArrayProcessor ap;

public Launcher(ArrayList al){
    this.al = al;
    ArrayProcessor ap = new ArrayProcessor(al);
}
public static void main(String[] args){
    ArrayList anArray = new ArrayList();
    anArray.add(new Integer(1));
    anArray.add(new Integer(13));
    anArray.add(new Integer(19));
    Launcher l = new Launcher(anArray);
    l.liftOff();
}

public void liftOff(){
    Thread t = new Thread(new Launcher(al));
    synchronized(t){
        t.start();
        try {
            t.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    this.ap = new ArrayProcessor(al);
    System.out.println("the array: " + ap.getArray());
}
public void run() {
    ap.doProcess(al);
}

}
```

and the called file:

```
public class ArrayProcessor extends Thread{

private ArrayList al;

public ArrayProcessor(ArrayList al){
    this.al = al; 
}

public void doProcess(ArrayList myAL){
    this.start();
}

public void run() {
            // this should increment the ArrayList elements by one
    for (int i=0; i<al.size(); i++){
        int num = ((Integer)al.get(i)).intValue();
        al.set(i, new Integer(++num));
    }
}

public ArrayList getArray(){
    return al;
}

}
```

Comment: It this swath of code really the smallest amount code that demonstrates the problem? I didn't think so... please read about [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) and prune the code in your question way down

Comment: @Bohemian fair comment. I'll try...

Comment: @Bohemian I agree with your comment. How about the new version?

Answer (score 0):

If you want one thread wait for another to finish you could use a **CountDownLatch**. Since there is a lot of code in your samples, here is a small POC:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                System.out.println("Thread doing some work...");
                Thread.sleep(10 * 1000);
                System.out.println("Thread done!");
                latch.countDown();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();


    System.out.println("Main Thread waiting...");
    latch.await();
    System.out.println("Main Thread can continue");
}
```